# Anchorlinks in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I created a menu in wordpress that both contains anchorlinks to different sections on the startpage, and links to other pages:

[image]

But when I navigate to another page (ex "Jobs"), and from there try to navigate in manu to a section on startpage - anchorlinks doesn't work because it needs the full URL to guide user back to startpage and then jump down to the section i clicked. But when I change anchorlinks to full url:

[image]

..it will allways reload, even if i'm on startpage because I have the full url. How do i create a menu that will only have section URL (ex "#meetups") on the startpage, and full URL (ex "/hip#meetups") when I'm on another page.

Can I build a javascript or PHP function for this?

I really got stuck here and will be incredibly thankful for any input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a jQuery function that will alter menu-link-attr/url depending on browser.location:

```
var x = location.pathname;
if(x === '/hip/jobs/'){
  var findLink = $('.menu-item-type-custom').find('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < findLink.size(); i++) {
    var attri = findLink.eq(i).attr('href');
    findLink.eq(i).attr('href', "http://localhost:3000/hip/" + attri);
  }
} else {
  console.log('error! ' + x);
}
```